# Means adjusted for covariates

Tags: r, survey, geometric-mean

I have been working to try to get means adjusted for covariates. I've seen examples such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567116/calculate-covariate-adjusted-means-and-95cis-for-treatment-and-control-group-se) one, but I haven't seen an example that has Dr. Lumley's `survey` package in R. The code I ran is:

```
library(nhanesA)
library(survey)

# Get data
bmx_d <- nhanes('BMX_D')
demo_d <- nhanes('DEMO_D')

# Merge them
bmx_demo <- merge(demo_d, bmx_d)

# Set up design
design <- svydesign(id = ~SDMVPSU,
                    strata = ~SDMVSTRA,
                    weights = ~WTMEC2YR,
                    nest = T,
                    data = bmx_demo)

# Linear model for arithmetic means
linmodel <- svyglm(BMXBMI ~ BMXWT, design = design)
print(summary(linmodel))

means <- svypredmeans(linmodel, ~RIDRETH1)
print('Arithmetic means:')
print(means)
print(confint(means))

# Linear model for geometric means
lingeomodel <- svyglm(log(BMXBMI) ~ BMXWT, design = design)
print(summary(lingeomodel))

geomeans <- exp(svypredmeans(lingeomodel, ~RIDRETH1))
print('Geometric means:')
print(geomeans)
print(confint(geomeans))
```

Estimating BMI as a function of body weight is a bit trivial, but I just wanted a minimum reproducible example.

More importantly, I want to know if I've correctly calculated arithmetic and geometric means of BMXBMI adjusted for race/ethnicity (RIDRETH1). If not, it is my lack of understanding of means adjusted for covariates that prevents me from understanding what to do.

Comment: Isn’t a mean adjusted for a covariate a regression?

Comment: Seems like you're having software trouble with the package, so does the question belong on Stackoverflow? If you can show the error message, it would help.

Comment: @AdamO, I'm more confused about the process than the code. The above code ran without errors.